# Android 34: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:35: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to select an image from storage, get its path, and then display the image using the path:

```
...

launcher = registerForActivityResult(
     new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
      result -> {
       if (result != null) {
          FilePathUri = result;
          try {

          Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri);
          String path = FilePathUri.getPath();

          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
          Bitmap bitmapFromPath = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
          imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapFromPath);  // gives error
          //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  //  it works fine - the image is displayed

          LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
          layout.addView(imageView);
...
```

When the image is selected, I get `Bitmap` which I then use to display the image in `ImageView`. It works, with the original `Bitmap`. However when I try to create a `Bitmap` using image path, I get an error:

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/document/image:35: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I need to be able to display an image by its path, because it's the path that I save in the database.

Comment: You already have the Uri, that is enough to display the image itself. You don't need to do any of this path stuff at all. If you want to [persist access to an image](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions), you need to use the [Photo Picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker) or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, not `GET_CONTENT`.

Answer (score 0):

Check filePathUri is exist or not if not exist first of all create folder then create path

```
    val path = File(this.externalCacheDir, "/Invoice")
    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdirs()
    }
    mFile = File("$path/", 
    singleInvoice.invoiceId+"_"+singleInvoice.invoice_type + ".pdf")
    if (!mFile!!.exists()){
     // complete your task
    }
```